# Magento2 override core module translation file not working

Tags: magento2, localisation

Want to update some labels from vendor\magento\module-fedex\i18n\en_US.csv file.

Like from Standard Overnight, Standard Overnight to

Standard Overnight,FedEx Overnight (1-2 business days).

How can i do that and want the same label update for admin side also.

Answer (score 4):

Core Module translations will not be overridden in custom theme so you need to place the new translations in your custom module folder. Create an empty module or use your existing module.

Just Copy this file  **vendor\magento\module-fedex\i18n\en_US.csv** and paste it to any of your extension **app\code\vendor\module\i18n**

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways to do that. Please check the documentation.

[https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/translations/theme_dictionary.html](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/translations/theme_dictionary.html#how-magento-applies-locales)